# QGIS Version 3.34 -Error during XML import

Tags: qgis, import, xml

When importing such an XML file into QGIS version 3.34, an object attribute (dientZurDarstellungVon) is not imported. There was no problem with this XML import in the previous version. The XML structure is correct. I suspect the issue is related to xlink declarations, which may not be supported by QGIS version 3.34. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a solution.

```
   <AP_PTO gml:id="DENIAL110j">
      <gml:identifier 
       codeSpace="http://www.advonline.de/">urn:adv:oid:DENIAL110j</gml:identifier>
      <lebenszeitintervall>
        <AA_Lebenszeitintervall>
          <beginnt>2022-07-27T15:17:18Z</beginnt>
        </AA_Lebenszeitintervall>
      </lebenszeitintervall>
      <modellart>
        <AA_Modellart>
          <advStandardModell>DKKM1000</advStandardModell>
        </AA_Modellart>
      </modellart>
      <position>
        <gml:Point gml:id="DENIAL110j_G0" srsName="urn:adv:crs:ETRS89_UTM32">
          <gml:pos>445161.836 5889225.500</gml:pos>
        </gml:Point>
      </position>
      <fontSperrung>0</fontSperrung>
      <skalierung>1</skalierung>
      <horizontaleAusrichtung>zentrisch</horizontaleAusrichtung>
      <vertikaleAusrichtung>Mitte</vertikaleAusrichtung>
      <art>Strasse</art>
      <dientZurDarstellungVon xlink:href="urn:adv:oid:DENIAL1100000" />
      <drehwinkel uom="urn:adv:uom:rad">5.5998853</drehwinkel>
    </AP_PTO>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not tied to the QGIS version used, but to the GDAL version.  GDAL 3.7 requires the use of NAS_GFS_TEMPLATE for the NAS driver (for GeoInfoDok 7 even GDAL 3.8 is required; see also https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/nas.html).